# How to return all "a" tags in a url and output them to the console using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Go to any website, as an example the homepage for stackoverflow. Open your dev tools and on the console write jQuery code to return all links on the page that contain this url stackapps.com

I know that

```
 $('a')
```

returns all links

Comment: Your expression is not clear

Comment: You want to select anchor tag that has URL of current page?

Comment: go to any website, as an example the homepage for stackoverflow. Open your dev tools and on the console write the jQuery code to return all links on the page that contain this url stackapps.com

Comment: What you want is Regular Expression

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
console.log($('a[href="www.stackapps.com"]'));
```

Or:

```
$('a[href="www.stackapps.com"]').each(function() {
  console.log($(this));
});
```